# PHP Get value from Json decode Response

Tags: php, json, curl, decode

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [AndroidNames] => Izzul [AndroidAddress] => Sukolilo [AndroidEmail] => izzul@ans.org [AndroidPhone] => 045345408596 [AndroidPayroll] => 423170721 [AndroidSex] => M [AndroidDateBirth] => Mar 22 1925 12:00AM [AndroidTitle] => Mr [AndroidDept] => IT [AndroidPos] => STAFF [ImagePath] => foto ) )
```

I have json decode response as above, I need to pull out AndroidDept only, but no result yet. Please help me figure it out.

I Have tried

```
$result = json_decode($response);
        foreach ($result as $object) {
            echo $object->AndroidDept . "<br/>";
        }
```

and

```
   $myJson = json_decode($response,true);
        
            foreach ($myJson as $object) {
                echo $object->AndroidDept . "<br/>";
            }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is that first code-formatted text the response? If so, that's not json, that's the `print_r()` output from an array of objects and you access it via `$response[0]->AndroidDept`.  Do you have error reporting turned on?  If you actually have a json string, then we need to see it in your question body.

Comment: Oh my bad, This is my very first using array. Let's say I  have that array. Could you please help me how to get AndroidDept Value. As I still get error. 

I have tried this 

 $response = curl_exec($client);
 $result = json_decode($response);
 $jab = count($result->result);
  
echo $response[0]->AndroidDept;


Thanks

Comment: Please show `var_export(curl_exec($client));`'s output.  I need to know exactly what the value is.

Comment: {"result":[{"AndroidNames":"Izzul","AndroidAddress":"Sukolilo ","AndroidEmail":"izzul@ans.com","AndroidPhone":"0857483424321","AndroidPayroll":"170721","AndroidSex":"M","AndroidDateBirth":"Mar 12 1995 12:00AM","AndroidTitle":"Mr","AndroidDept":"IT","AndroidPos":"STAFF","ImagePath":"foto"}]}

Comment: https://3v4l.org/ePVBT `var_export(json_decode(curl_exec($client))->result[0]->AndroidDept);`  The first level is an object, so access `->result`.  The next level is an indexed array and you want to access the first element so access `[0]`.  The next level is an object, so access `->AndroidDept`.